# Can an address of an instant of a template to a function be passed as a pointer to function to some function?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, function-pointers

I have the following code which compiles without any problem

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

template<typename T>
void compare(const std::vector<T> &v1, const std::vector<T> &v2, void(*func)(const int&,const int&,const size_t&))
{
    size_t minLen{v1.size() < v2.size() ? v1.size() : v2.size()};

    for(size_t index{}; index<minLen; index++)
        func(v1[index],v2[index],index);

}

template<typename T>
void matcher(const T& val1,const T& val2,const size_t& index)
{
    if(val1==val2) std::cout<<"v1 and v2 are equal at index "<<index<<"\n";

}


int main()
{
    std::vector v1={1,5,-9,-8};
    std::vector v2={1,5,-9,-80,45};
    compare(v1,v2,&(matcher<int>));
    return 0;
}
```

Now I have the following question : Is `compare(v1,v2,&(matcher<int>));` equivalent to `compare(v1,v2,&matcher);` and why

An Edit

When I delete the `const` before `index` var in matcher, the compiler shows the following error

```
temp.cpp(85): error C2664: 'void compare1<int>(const std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>> &,const std::vector<int,std::allocator<int>> &,void (__cdecl *)(const int &,const int &,const size_t &))': cannot convert argument 3 from 'void (__cdecl *)(const T &,const T &,size_t &)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(const int &,const int &,const size_t &)'
temp.cpp(85): note: None of the functions with this name in scope match the target type
temp.cpp(64): note: see declaration of 'compare1'
```

The compiler says

```
'void (__cdecl *)(const T &,const T &,size_t &)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(const int &,const int &,const size_t &)'
```

It doesn't say

```
'void (__cdecl *)(const int &,const int &,size_t &)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(const int &,const int &,const size_t &)'
```

Comment: @MooingDuck I'm very sorry. See edits

Comment: They are not equivalent. The only reason the latter works is because you are doing the equivalent of casting to a function-pointer.

Comment: @super: I think the addition clarifies the problem

Comment: No, it does not. Why does the error message surprise you? If the compiler can't find a match it will show you the actual signature of the template.

Comment: @super but I forced it to use the one using int no using the generic type. Does the compiler show the generic type signature even if I force it to use a certain instant

Comment: The compilation failed at that point though. I don't know if the standard has anything to say about it, but it seems strange that the compiler would guarantee that the template still gets instatiated so you can get an arguably equivalent error message. For reference, latest GCC says `cannot convert '& matcher<int>' (type '<unresolved overloaded function type>') to type 'void (*)(const int&, const int&, const size_t&)'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`compare(v1,v2,&matcher);` works because of [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction#Address_of_an_overload_set).

> Template argument deduction is used when taking an [address of a overload set](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address), which includes function templates.

and

> If the function name names a function template, then, first, [template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) is done, and if it succeeds, it produces a single template specialization which is added to the set of overloads to consider.

The 3rd function parameter type of `compare` is `void(*func)(const int&,const int&,const size_t&)`, when pass `&matcher`, the template parameter `T` of `matcher` is deduced as `int`, the effect is just same as specifying the template argument explicitly as `matcher<int>`.

BTW: What kind of message get printed out depends on the implementation of compiler; e.g. [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QEbt7gFz4bRhauC1) gives different one.

Comment: I know that but why the compiler didn't say that it says the types are `T` not `int`

Comment: @anonymous What kind of message get printed out depends on the implementation of compiler; e.g. [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QEbt7gFz4bRhauC1) gives different one.

Comment: @ songyuanyao I think this can be an answer

Comment: @anonymous Fine, added.

Answer (score 1):

`matcher` is a template, used to generate normal C++ functions. `matcher<int>` is a perfectly normal C++ function. So `matcher<int>` is indeed a `void(*func)(const int&,const int&,const size_t&)`, but no, `matcher` is not a function, it is a template.

I didn't think you could pass the `matcher` template to `compare`, but [HTNW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5684257/htnw) [proved me wrong](https://godbolt.org/z/RxGmj1). Apparently the compiler is smart enough to deduce the template arguments when coercing a template to a function function pointer. Neat.  This sort of template deduction usually doesn't work with class templates.

Comment: It is apparently a C++17 thing: https://tio.run/##fVLBToQwEL33KyZrQkCKWYgbdbfgD3jcmxrTlLI2gYJQGpXw62KhsKvZKJfOzJt5mfcGVlUBy6k8DMOFkCxvU05E2aia0yJBx5LmTJV1gpDiRZVTxYn6qLikBYd9gnQpUmBlUdGau6yUjYJGpdutnSL7BBwdYvgDiTCMBO5l1krmzfNCKgefhY345C/K8TzUITCfzaEQ8oHLTodXY8H1gICOlvgeTvXtqd7v0ESRlbU70wiZ8veu39mAWNY5831vap9GzJ6uDh8n4BnraImmxzPE/X9GFVSxV17PQvcOaJqH@GcW/ZZrN1g0i8wdB@J4bPSsnaxsFSErHQKVqdEI5hDA31qaA511wYoQq4usnuTKLomMt2YfId2jo6frGN/iLsQbHNzh4Nb4dYZHP/A1vt7MPcufYG5ujuvMej0L1ly1tYT1DvXD8MWynB6aITC0MfP98OYb

Comment: @HTNW Whoa! I got used to class templates not being deducable in most contexts, and didn't realize function templates might differ. Thanks for the correction!

Comment: In particular, notice the reduced syntax for `vector`.

Comment: @jxh No, it is not C++17 specific. The error from earlier versions is because the template arguments to `std::vector` cannot be deduced. https://godbolt.org/z/AbPUc2. The [cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overloaded_address) has no boxes around the important bits; this behavior seems to be very old.